# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have installed Crystal Report version 13.0.21.2533. I have also added reference in my project (which is a windows application). I am facing the issue while opening the report.cs file as

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." in visual
>   studio.

Any ideas how it can be resolved, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Error : crystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer,
>   Version=13.0.2000.0

If your app is running in x86 just download the [CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_20](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_20.exe) and install it. That worked for me.